# Is there a list of software vendors that Ubuntu makes use of?

Tags: canonical, proprietary, open-source

This is not a technical question, but I hope it's relevant enough to be worthy of an answer.

I'm doing some research about Ubuntu for a project at my university. I am curious to see if there is a comprehensive list of software vendors that Ubuntu/Canonical makes use of. I've been doing research for the past hour, but I have been unable to find specifics as to which companies Ubuntu relies on or makes use of. To give an example, some products make use of companies like Microsoft, as Microsoft provides them with the .NET Framework. This makes Microsoft a software vendor of a product that the product relies on.

Comment: Companies?  Ubuntu is open source - and all upstream projects are open source (and have a compatible licence) in order to be considered for inclusion. Refer https://www.ubuntu.com/licensing which highlights the open-source, few companies release full code in open-source but often only parts (eg. Microsoft keeping control) thus make inclusion impossible. Upstream is the Gnome Project, Debian Open Document Foundation & lots of projects, but few companies unless you see links to Linux Foundation thru use of Linux kernel source.   Microsoft & corps are generally downstream (users of open-source)

Comment: Microsoft & companies may be members of foundations & organizations that support open-source, for example if you look at https://www.linuxfoundation.org/membership/members/ you can see the whole list of companies that provide $s that help create the code. They are supporters and suppliers (except of $s).  If they throw-in-enough-$s they can have a seat on the board (which Microsoft does), but supporters and suppliers are not the same.

Comment: The term "vendor" means a *commercial relationship* exists. This is the case ONLY for the Canonical Partners repo, and nowhere in a plain install of Ubuntu (Partners is not part of the stock install). In the Partners repo, Canonical is generally the vendor providing a distribution platform from other software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Companies? Ubuntu is open source - and all upstream projects are open source (and have a compatible licence) in order to be considered for inclusion. Refer https://www.ubuntu.com/licensing which highlights the open-source, few companies release full code in open-source but often only parts (eg. Microsoft keeping control) thus make inclusion impossible.

*Most corporations provide only binary-blobs so cannot be included in 'main' or 'universe', and thus go into 'resticted' or 'multiverse' which users can use if they so decide (but require download as not included on install media).  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu*

Upstream is the Gnome Project (https://www.gnome.org/foundation/), Debian (https://www.debian.org/),  Open Document Foundation (https://www.documentfoundation.org/) & lots of other projects, but few companies unless you see links to Linux Foundation thru use of Linux kernel source. Microsoft & corps are generally downstream (users of open-source)

Microsoft & companies may be members of foundations & organizations that support open-source, for example if you look at https://www.linuxfoundation.org/membership/members/ you can see the whole list of companies that provide $s that help create the code. They are supporters and suppliers (except of $s). If they *throw in enough $s* they can have a seat on the board (which Microsoft does), but supporters and suppliers are not the same.

There are benefits (and reduced costs) to being involved in the creation of open-source code you use, which companies at first don't realize (happily just take & use) slowly realizing having to re-patch & support older versions costs more than pushing changes upstream and making patches live thru upgrades, but this takes time to realize.

I'm assuming your research involves companies/corporations - which are downstream users on open-source projects generally, usually supporting the projects through $s (either direct to foundations, or paying for developers to write code for inclusion into the open-source project; which do not get recorded against any company, the code-changelog only shows developer).